# Fitted values above one in a logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model

I have a binary dependent variable (`R`) and four numeric independent variables (`Q, M, S, T`) and want to examine coefficients for them.

Here is my glm code in R:

```
fit = glm(R ~ Q + M + S + T, data=data, family=binomial())
```

When I run `predict(fit)`, I get a lot of predicted values greater than one (but none below 0 so far as I can tell). I have tried bayesglm and glmnet per suggestions to similar questions but both are a little over my head and the output I did get didn't seem to fix my problem.

I want to know:
A) Is this typical of logistic regression?
B) If not, how do I fix it?

Comment: The OP's mistake is a pure coding question, but what led the OP to realise there was a problem (i.e. whether there could be predicted values above 1) is a statistical issue. I think "if you are producing fitted values above 1 in a logistic regression, then you must have made a mistake in your code" is a learning point that belongs on a statistics site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that predict has a **"type= c("link", "response", "terms")"** argument:

```
type    
the type of prediction required. The default is on the scale of the linear 
predictors; the alternative "response" is on the scale of the response variable. 
Thus for a default binomial model the default predictions are of log-odds 
(probabilities on logit scale) and type = "response" gives the predicted probabilities. 
The "terms" option returns a matrix giving the fitted values of each term in the model 
formula on the linear predictor scale.
```

Default is **link** but you are looking for **response**.

Is it typical of logistic regression ? Not that I know. It is mostly a choice of implementation, both quantities can be useful depending on the situation.
 **Python sk-learn** implements both **predict_proba** and **predict_log_proba**.

Comment: Thanks! I initially thought I saw responses greater than one but I guess I was misreading. Everything looks good now.

Comment: Thanks, adding the info about Python was quite nice, and I agree with "It is mostly a choice of implementation, both quantities can be useful depending on the situation" - but that wasn't quite what I meant ;) More a (brief!) explanation about *what* the two quantities actually represent statistically (and an affirmation that the fitted response would, indeed, be between 0 and 1 ... the OP was originally confused why the fitted response, which represented a probability could be above one, and the answer is that it isn't!).